# How can i direct link into page in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5.4, adminlte

AdminLTE Laravel template screenshoot:

[image]

how can i direct the link into my page in folder lapor/one.blade.php and lapor/two.blade.php?

```
<li class="treeview">
  <a><i class='fa fa-file'></i> <span>Laporan</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><a href="{{ url('') }}">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('') }}">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    Before going to redirect the page two steps you need to do :



     Step 1:

        Define Methods in controller(named as SampleController) for example:

        //Controller Name:SampleController
       // Method Names defined in controller :lapor1,lapor2


    //Method 1
    public function lapor1(){
        return view('lapor.one');
        }
        //Method 2
        public function lapor2(){
        return view('lapor.two');
        }

   Step :2

    Define Routes for the pages like below:
    Route::get('lapor1', ['as' => 'laporone','uses'=>'SampleController@lapor1']);
    Route::get('lapor2', ['as' => 'laportwo','uses'=>'SampleController@lapor2']);

    Step 3:

    Link up to view pages now:
    <li><a href="/lapor1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/lapor2">Two</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a route like below

```
  Route::get('one', function () {
        return view('lapor.one');
    });
    Route::get('two', function () {
        return view('lapor.two');
    });
```

And link it like below

```
 <li><a href="/one">One</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would group your adminLTE routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);

    Route::get('users', ['as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'AdminController@users']);

});
```

We prefixed those routes with /admin/ or whatever you want to call it. Then we prefixed their name with admin (using 'as').

Now get a specific route url:

```
{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}
```

**Why do it like this?**

Naming your routes is very important because if the route url changes and your app has hardcored urls (like url('/admin/dashboard') your entire application will break. With named routes this wont happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three step:

1. make a function in your controller.like below

   publice function functionName(){
    return view('yourpagename(one)');
   }
2. go to routes folder open web.php and connect with your controller function in routes. like

   Route::get('page-name', 'controllerName@functionName');
3. add this url to your view page link tag

   {{URL::to('page-name')}}

Hope it will works fine.